# GridView with 2 rows and multiple Columns Horizontal Scroll Dynamically in Android

Tags: android, gridview, horizontal-scrolling

I am having an issue with `GridView`. I need a Horizontal Scroll, with a `GridView` that has 2 rows and multiple columns, depending on dynamic data. Does anybody know about how it could be achieved? I tried with `TableLayout` in `ScrollView`, but that is scrolling each table row individually. I need both rows to be scrolled when user swipes the screen.

Can any one please let me know, if this could be done. If so, any reference or sample. Please help and thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

you should use scrollview with views inside that you place yourself programmatically

OR

Use a tiers library, for example : https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Answer (score -1):

You can use `HorizontalScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`. Just like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
  <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout id="first_row" orientation="horizontal">
      // Add custom view programmatically inside this first row 
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout id="second_row" orientation="horizontal">
     // Add custom view programmatically inside this second row 
   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Hope this helps you, and ask me in case of query